# How to apply a loop with in the Regex function in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to use a Regex function to find keywords in a large text file and then pick a certain value in the text file corresponding to it. While my current script does this, I want to put a loop within the Regex function so that I can do it for multiple (>100) keywords. For example: In my text, B443 would be searched and a number written next to it would be picked. The text looks like this :

*

(BHC443) 2,462,000
  1.a.(1)(a) (b) All other loans secured by real estate 
(BHC442) 1,033,000
  1.a.(1)(b)

*

The output would be BHC443:2,462,000, BHC:442:1,033,000 etc. for all the keywords searched. Now, I have many more keywords in the text for which I need to pick the corresponding numbers and I want to write a dynamic regex function such that it takes the keywords one by one and generates outputs. I have a fixed list of keywords already sorted out (e.g., B443, B442, CA13323,SQDS73733 etc.). So the problem is searching for all those in the text and then picking up numbers probably by importing the keywords as a list first, and then running the regex function over the elements of that list. I don't know how to run a loop for that.
The regex code I wrote for finding the number corresponding to one keyword at a time is written below and it works.

```
with open(path, 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
      key_value_name = re.search('(B443)([\\(\\)((\\s)+)|(\\n)?(\\n)])
([1234567890,a-zA-Z.\\s]+)', line) # For each keyword, pick the 
corresponding amount
      if key_value_name:
        print(key_value_name.group(1))
        print(key_value_name.group(3))
```

Comment: Your regex doesn't make a lot of sense. **#1** Explain what is supposed to match, because you almost certainly got it wrong. **#2** Also, explain what the difference between the two expressions is and how the other > 100 would look like and **#3** show a sample of your input as well as **#4** the results you expect from that input sample.

Comment: Please give examples of input and expected output.